# How to write unit test for a route/endpoint with authorization in header?

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, auth0

I'm writing this route with Spring Boot and authorization using auth0.
it's supposed to return 401 when it has no authorization in header, and return 200 when has a valid auth0 id_token in header. What is a proper way to write unit test for it?

To get authorization in header, should I get a real id_token, or is there a way to mock one? If I should use a real id_token, is it proper to store it as a string in the test code, or should I store it somewhere else (eg. as an environment variable) to protect it?

Answer (score 0):

Spring has `@WithMockUser` annotation in order to help testing methods where there is a need for an authenticated user. This can be used as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyControllerTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(context)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    public void shouldUpdateEntry() throws Exception {
        ....
    }
}
```

Please note that this does not tests the authentication itself. `@WithMockUser` meant to be used to test methods which are running with a given privilege.